# Filtering problem

Tags: custom-post-types, mysql, meta-query

I got the custom_post_type_data in which I store some variables when I make a new post. Variables likes Author, Price etc.
I implemented a filtering by author, so when you click on James (for example), you will see all James`s products. All seemed nice until now. Today I discovered a little bug (At James products page, there are some other authors products listed). I do not know why exactly, but I guess I will need to be more specific, by adding a "%" after $author (James). The problem is that this will not work at all. Any idea why?

```
  'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'custom_post_type_data',
        'value' => $author,
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

> ... I will need to be more specific, by adding a "%" after $author
>   (James). The problem is that this will not work at all. Any idea why?

The `%` is a wildcard with a MySQL `LIKE` query, which I suspect you know. With meta queries, WordPress will add one to the beginning and one to the end of the string you provide. [You can see that in the source.](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/meta.php#L806) or just by `var_dump`ing the query. By adding a `%` of your own, I suspect is throwing things off. By the time `WP_Query` and `wpdb` is through with it, it ends up looking like `\\%%`. I just ran a query through to check that.

Unfortunately the `LIKE` meta_query is not very flexible, but [maybe you could sort it out with the `get_meta_sql` filter](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/meta.php#L830).